# Why is a category missing from the list of possible categories (as provided by the YouTube Data API) but is still assignable to a video?

Tags: youtube-data-api

When I call the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list) for listing video categories, I get a list that excludes one that I regularly use when I manually upload a video or manually create live stream.

For example, the API referenced above does not return an entry for "Nonprofits & Activism".
But, when I manually try to assign a category to an uploaded video or live stream, "Nonprofits & Activism" is one of the options.

I found out that the id of "Nonprofits & Activism" is 29, via this link:
https://gist.github.com/dgp/1b24bf2961521bd75d6c?permalink_comment_id=3891118

Furthermore, when I use the [video update API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) to try to associate the category "Nonprofits & Activism", whose id is 29, with my video, it associates it just fine.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) suggests that one should "*Use the videoCategories.list method to retrieve supported categories.*"

Is this is a bug or am I missing something?